# Making a curved road texture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, creative-cloud

I have a very simple road texture (`200 x 200`) like this:

[image: road texture 1]

I need to create a curved version of this texture that is double the size (`400 x 400`). Here is a picture to give you a basic idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image: curved road texture]

The problem is, I have no idea how to curve the lines and the road markings in such a way that they would form smooth curves that tile seamlessly with the original texture. I have tried using the warp tool (I have the lines and markings all as separate layers), but the results look horrible. I'm pretty sure there is a pretty simple solution to this, but I'm rather inexperienced with photoshop. I've been banging my head against a wall because of this for the last two hours, so any help would be greatly apprectiated. And yes, I have tried to google for tutorials, but haven't been able to find anything that would address this issue clearly.

I'm using Photoshop CC. I also have Illustrator but zero experience using it.

Comment: You ask about doing this in Photoshop, fine, but the easiest way to produce a good result (no blurry texture) would be to recreate it in Illustrator with the Brush tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this problem by using the `bézier pen tool` in Photoshop or Illustrator. This allows you to "draw" mathematically-defined vectors and shapes that have the added benefit of being able to scale to any size without losing resolution.

But here's the thing: learning the bézier pen tool is challenging as it doesn't work like the other pixel-based tools that Photoshop provides - you have to think of it as building lines and shapes.

To help you get started, you might want to try practicing The Bézier Game: http://bezier.method.ac/ . Once you've mastered the bézier pen tool though, you can easily accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Has this question been answered elsewhere? Answer 1 doesn't even come close to addressing the original request (Illustrator is unhelpful in this request, unless you create your textures in that program to begin with). Of course, this bloody web site won't let me post more than 2 pictures unless I'm a long-time member, so I've just jumbled them all into one big pic, sorry about that.

Here's how you do it:
Disclaimer A - you WILL have artifacts and stretched textures, this is not magic.
Disclaimer B - Yisela was correct in one thing: you will need to understand how to edit Bezier curves, but in this context, it's not like you need to be an expert.

First, set up your vertical and a horizontal texture like below, where the textures are EXACTLY proportional to the curvature. In this case, I'm doing a 90 degree bend, so the textures are square.

Fig 1.

Then, you need to draw some guidelines, use the built-in Photoshop guidelines to create a grid, like so, and a circular outline on a separate layer at about 25% opacity on major features of your texture (such as the middle of the road, sidewalk, etc.).

Fig 2.
 Fig 3.

Then, you need to create a copy of your texture in another layer and double it up, either horizontally or vertically. I chose vertically:

Fig 4.

Once that's done, select "Edit/Transform/Warp" and move the mesh points around until it looks like this, then hit "Enter":

Fig 5.
 Fig 6.

Voila:

Fig 7.

[image: Making a curved road texture in Photoshop]